# How to remove common words in a paragraph phrased using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nlp

I need a way to remove the common words within the above phrased content of a webpage. how to integrate such method.

`third_headers = ' '.join([r.text for r in soup.find_all('h3')]) third_headers`

I got an Output - 'HTML and CSS Data Analytics XML Tutorials JavaScript Programming Server Side Web Building Data Analytics XML Tutorials HTML CSS JavaScript Programming Server Side XML Character Sets Exercises Quizzes Courses Certificates Example Example Explained'

Need a new output without common words ( common words removed using from a common word corpus)

Comment: Do you have such a corpus of common words? If yes what's its shape and type?

Comment: No, I dont have such corpus. Im not aware on how to link a corpus to remove the common words to be Stemmed later.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by common words? You should an output you don't want. What does the expected output look like?

Comment: The Expected output should be the above shown paragraph without common words. Common words can be ( and , if , yes , no etc) from a common word corpus.

Comment: Well the only thing is to find such a corpus. The rest is just filtering

Comment: Is your question how to find such a corpus then? If not, if I can assume we have the corpus, say in a list, I can right the answer

Comment: Assuming a corpus is used to filter the paragraph without the common words  is what I needed. And how to link the corpus to filter the text without common words.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'll add my answer see if that's what you need.

Comment: Basically to remove all the common words from any way and filter out the uncommon words will be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have a corpus of common words in a list called `CORPUS`:

```
raw = 'HTML and CSS Data Analytics XML Tutorials JavaScript Programming Server Side Web Building Data Analytics XML Tutorials HTML CSS JavaScript Programming Server Side XML Character Sets Exercises Quizzes Courses Certificates Example Example Explained'


CORPUS = ["And", "So", "If", "etc."]           # assumed to have
corpus = [w.lower() for w in CORPUS]           # to lowercase

words = raw.split()
processed = [w for w in words if w.lower() not in corpus]

print(processed)
```

Comment: Just some suggestions: I'd use `raw.split()` without any arguments, which will also split at newlines and won't give you empty tokens in case of consecutive spaces. Those "common words" are called *stop words* in NLP. You can get them, e.g., with `from nltk.corpus import stopwords; corpus = stopwords.words('english')`.

Comment: Thanks. I updated to `raw.split()`. 
Also good to know about the `nltk.corpus import stopwords`